# Toggle between plotly bar chart to plotly column chart by using an actionButton

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have the `shiny` app below which displays a bar chart with `Country` in `yaxis` and `Value` in `xaxis`. Im trying to change it to: `Country` as `xaxis` and `Value` as `yaxis` by clicking on `Exchange` `actionButton()`. I should toggle between those two bu clicking on `Exchange`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

Country<-c("EU","CHE","ITA")
Value<-c(3,2,1)
dat<-data.frame(Country,Value)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      
      actionButton("exc",
                   "Exchange")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId = "plot")
      
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  excplot <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$exc, {
    excPlot(!excplot())
  })
  
  
  output[["bar1"]]<-renderPlotly({
        fig1 <- plot_ly(dat, x = ~Value, y = ~Country,
                        type = 'bar', orientation = 'h',
                        hovertemplate = paste('%{y}', '<br>Value: %{x}<br>'),
                        marker = list(color = 'green')
        ) 
        fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(
          
          yaxis = list(title="",showgrid = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, domain= c(0, 0.85)),
          xaxis = list(title="",zeroline = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE)) 
        fig1 <- fig1 %>% add_annotations(xref = 'x1', yref = 'y',
                                         x =  dat$Value* 1.1 + 0.5,  y = dat$Country,
                                         text = paste(round(dat$Value, 2), '%'),
                                         font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12, color = 'black'),
                                         showarrow = FALSE)
        fig1 
      })
  
  output$plot <- renderUI({
    plotlyOutput("bar1")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Why not define a second bar plot as `output$bar2` and toggle between them in `renderUI()`?

Comment: Im trying to achieve it inside one renderPlotly cause my original app is more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will meet your needs.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

Country<-c("EU","CHE","ITA")
Value<-c(3,2,1)
dat<-data.frame(Country,Value)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("exc", "Exchange")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId = "plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  excplot <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$exc, {
    excplot(!excplot())
  })
  
  
  output[["bar1"]]<-renderPlotly({
    if (excplot()) {
      dat$xvar <- dat$Value
      dat$yvar <- dat$Country
      hv <- "h"
      myyaxis = list(title="",showgrid = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, domain= c(0, 0.85) )
      myxaxis = list(title="",zeroline = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE) 
      xx <- dat$xvar*1.1 + 0.1
      yy <- dat$yvar
    }else {
      dat$yvar <- dat$Value
      dat$xvar <- dat$Country
      hv <- "v"
      myxaxis = list(title="",showgrid = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, domain= c(0, 0.85) )
      myyaxis = list(title="",zeroline = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE) 
      xx <- dat$xvar
      yy <- dat$yvar*1.1 + 0.1
    }
    
    fig1 <- plot_ly(dat, x = ~xvar, y = ~yvar,
                    type = 'bar', orientation = hv,
                    hovertemplate = paste('%{y}', '<br>Value: %{x}<br>'),
                    marker = list(color = 'green')
    ) 
    fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(yaxis = myyaxis, xaxis = myxaxis ) 
    fig1 <- fig1 %>% add_annotations(xref = 'x1', yref = 'y',
                                     x = xx ,  y =  yy,
                                     text = paste(round(dat$Value, 2), '%'),
                                     font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12, color = 'black'),
                                     showarrow = FALSE)
    fig1 
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderUI({
    plotlyOutput("bar1")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: this is what I was asking for

Comment: based on your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67197410/toggle-between-more-than-2-plots-using-the-same-actionbutton-in-shiny-app