# Toggle between more than 2 plots using the same actionButton() in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below in which I want to toggle between 3 plots using the same `actionButton()`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("exc", "Exchange")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId = "plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  excplot <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$exc, {
    excplot(!excplot())
  })
  
  
  output[["bar1"]]<-renderPlot({
    if (excplot()) {
      fig1 <- plot(iris
      ) 
      
      fig1 
    }else {
      fig1 <- plot(mtcars
      ) 
      
      fig1 
    }
    #else {
     # fig1 <- plot(iris3
      #) 
      
      #fig1 
    #}
    
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("bar1")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice way to do this (iterate through 3 options by pressing one button to toggle between them) is to first understand that you can access the value of an action button via `input` in the `server` section.  Each time the user presses the button in the app you shared, the value of `input$exc` will increment by 1.

You can use this to your advantage to realize that you can determine which plot to show based on the value of the button and the mod (`%%`) operator.  Thus, `input$exc %% 3` can be used to cycle through values equal to 1, 2, and 0.  Map that value to the plot you want to show and you have a way to do what you describe.

In the app below, you'll see I added a `textOutput()` UI element that show the current value of the button so you can see what's going on.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("exc", "Exchange"),
      textOutput('button_value')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId = "plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output[["bar1"]]<-renderPlot({
    if (input$exc %% 3 == 1)
      plot(iris)
    else if (input$exc %% 3 == 2)
      plot(mtcars)
    else
      plot(CO2)
  })
  
  output$button_value <- renderText(paste('Current Value of Button:', input$exc))
  
  output$plot <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("bar1")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It's notable that you don't need to setup a `reactiveVal` or use `observeEvent()` or setup another observer to make this work.  `input$exc` is reactive, so it will update when you click the button anyway.